# MySQL default user

Tags: mysql, users

I have `mysql.user` table with this content:

`select host, user, password from user;`

```
| localhost  | root | *75267AEB7355CEEE80EAB92D19FF50095AD9BB3E |
| linux      | root |                                           |
| localhost  |      |                                           |
| linux      |      |                                           |
```

Is is safe to remove last 3 lines? since I never login to database without password? or those are default users for MySQL on windows that should not be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** If you have important data on your server, backup before you perform any of these operations. I did not exhaustively test my solution.

**To answer this, I did the following on Windows and Linux**

(example shown is for Linux)

- Logged on - selected from user table.
- Deleted all users except the root one with password.
- Logged out, then logged back in again.
- Checked that I could perform various operations - they all worked (more than shown - e.g. create table).

So, the answer to your question is that **yes, you can do what you ask.**

But, I would also say that logging on as root on a regular basis is poor practice (if your data is important). If it's a dev/test server, that's not an issue.

**Operations Performed.**

```
mysql> select host, user, password from user;
+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| host                  | user     | password                                  |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost             | root     | *381AD08BBFA647B14C82AC1094A29AD4D7E4F51D |
| localhost.localdomain | root     |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1             | root     |                                           |
| ::1                   | root     |                                           |
| localhost             |          |                                           |
| localhost.localdomain |          |                                           |
| localhost             | bugs     | *381AD08BBFA647B14C82AC1094A29AD4D7E4F51D |
| %                     | bugs     |                                           |
| localhost             | puser    | *9F8D1F4C5ECC93C1D04F6BF04508FEDE4A9CF7F3 |
| localhost             | MY_USER  | *B678380CFA4459BB48E7B66AE1341F5F5B97D14E |
| localhost             | testuser | *00E247AC5F9AF26AE0194B41E1E769DEE1429A29 |
| 12.23.*.*             |          |                                           |
| 85.*.*.*              |          |                                           |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

So then I did (deleting all records except the first one).

```
mysql> delete from user where host <> 'localhost';
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> delete from user where user <> 'root';
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And the I selected from the user table.

```
mysql> select host, user, password from user;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root | *381AD08BBFA647B14C82AC1094A29AD4D7E4F51D |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Exited and then logged in again.

```
[pol@localhost inst]$ !904
./bin/mysql --defaults-file=./my.cnf -S ./mysql.sock -u root -p
Enter password:     
mysql> use test;

Database changed
mysql> show tables like 'z%';
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_test (z%) |
+---------------------+
| zsample             |
| zz                  |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

So, I can still select - but can I perform other operations?

```
mysql> select * from zsample;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from zsample where x = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from zsample;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```